# How to uninstall Ubuntu from inside itself

Tags: upgrade, dual-boot, uninstall

I want to upgrade to 32-bit 11.10 but I can't seem to get rid of Ubuntu 10.04. I have Windows 7 but no admin rights, so I can't remove it, and the admin won't do it because he doesn't know what he's doing.

Answer (score 5):

If you just begin the 11.10 install, you can choose to overwrite the old partition with 10.04. No need to uninstall it first.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to install from CD or USB, boot from that media and when the installer asks, choose replace existing Linux system. If from wubi, I would guess that you need administrative rights on the computer.